# Can two SAP GUI scripts be joined while working on an open connection with the help of VBA?

Tags: vba, automation, scripting, sap-gui

I am trying to run a script on SAP GUI using VBA. My script successfully opens the firefighter ID, but it fails to go to the other script which has been recorded.

Is there any way to join two scripts while an SAP GUI session is open in VBA?

Comment: "it fails to go to the other script which has been recorded". What is the code that you use? In what way does it fail? any errors?

Comment: I am trying to extract some data from table. This data stores in excel and then in the next step I call the Archival program in sap which archives that data. Now the problem here comes is, Due to access restrictions in SAP, We use Firefigter id which have maximum roles. So my one part of the script opens the Fire fighter system E9P in this case. Then once the grc tcode is entered, the Firefighter redirects the system to Production system E1P where all the process starts. Now here the VBA scripts fails because it cannot detect that jump of the system.

Comment: I continuation, So i need some thing or some way through which I can attach my script to ongoing session of SAP...

Comment: Here, words are not sufficient to understand/reproduce your issue. I don't even undertand what issue you have (does the word "fails" means that your computer gets on fire?) Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If not, please see the Help center about how to ask questions.

Comment: If you're talking about scripting to get around SAP licencing restrictions, I'm sure all of those holes were closed long ago.